# echo literal question mark in PS1

Tags: shell, prompt

I'm new to shell scripting and trying to make myself a nice prompt to show me the state of my git branch, using colors and characters like "?".

when I have new untracked files, I want my PS1 to be like:

```
p/a/t/h/ (staging ?) $
```

i.e. pwd (branchName space questionMark) $

I've simplified my problem to this code (~/.bashrc):

```
parseGitBranch () {
     gitBranch=staging
     ifUntrackedFiles="$gitBranch ?"
     echo $ifUntrackedFiles
 }

 PS1="`parseGitBranch` $ "
```

My problem is that because of the space before the question mark, PS1 treats it as a wildcard and shows me any single letter file exists in my directory.

```
p/a/t/h/ (staging ?) touch a
p/a/t/h/ (staging ?) source ~/.bashrc
p/a/t/h/ (staging a) $
```

Without the space it works well but I still want the space after my branch name :\

```
p/a/t/h/ (staging?) $
```

I've also tried:

```
ifUntrackedFiles="$gitBranch"' ?'
```

`echo -e`

and a backslash before the mark outputs them both (staging \?)

How to escape the question mark in PS1?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Bourne shell, not quoting a variable (i.e. `$var` instead of `"$var"`) should be the exception. The problem here is your `echo` command. With `echo ?`, `?` is substituted with every one-letter file in your directory, whereas with `echo "?"`, the question mark is displayed as is.

Your function should then be:

```
parseGitBranch () {
     gitBranch=staging
     ifUntrackedFiles="$gitBranch ?"
     echo "$ifUntrackedFiles"
 }
```

And, since back-quotes are easy to confuse with single quotes and difficult to nest, use `$(...)` instead:

```
 PS1='$(parseGitBranch) $ '
```